# How to select colour from the colour picker window in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to select colour from the colour picker window in automation throught protractor.
Scenario is : I have to design a screen and pick colour for different title, body etc.
As soon as I click on that element, colour picker window gets opened.

HTML code for elements is

```
    <div class="app_provision" ng-hide="appDetails.operating_system=='THIRD_PARTY'">
<div id="app-heading-div">
<div class="user-detail">
<label class="label_normal bold-label">Title Color</label>
<input id="title-color" class="textbox ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" type="color" style="width:240px;" ng-model="appDetails.title_color">
</div>
<div class="user-detail">
<label class="label_normal bold-label">Title Text Color</label>
<input id="title-text-color" class="textbox ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" type="color" style="width:240px;" ng-model="appDetails.title_text_color">
</div>
```

[Image depicts the scenario of colour picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHiT5.png)

Comment: so the color picker popup is a desktop application, right?

Comment: yes. @SudharsanSelvaraj

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control this popup through selenium, set the color by *sending keys* to the `input`:

```
var colorInput = element(by.model("appDetails.title_color"));
colorInput.sendKeys("#ff0000");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you pasted the complete HTML snippet, but there should be a `<form>` around the `input` element and try to submit the `form`

```
element(by.css('#title-color')).sendKeys('#000000')
element(by.css('#title-color')).submit()
```

Comment: @alecxe Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my response